# Adapt a drawn overlay to match roads

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, mkmapview, mapkit, core-location

In my application I can draw an overlay (PolyLine) on my map (MKMapView). This overlay however, is not bounded to actual roads. Is there a way (some API or others) to adapt the overlay so that it covers/overlays a real road.

The application is run on mobile devices (iPod Touch & iPhone), so to not make my app a very battery consuming one, I would set the Core Location Accuracy not to the highest. As a result, the location will be a bit next to the road where you are. Then I would still like my program to adjust this error...

Comment: There isn't a way to get the actual road position from the MKMapView at least.  One alternative is to first draw another polyline underneath the "main" polyline.  The first (bottom) polyline's width would be based on the accuracy and you can set its alpha to less than 1.  Similar to the accuracy rings around the user location but without the animation.

Answer (score 0):

To get an overlay that matches actual roads, I used Google Maps API Webservices. I already had an array of all points forming a route and I used these points (coordinates) to easily create an overlay that maps on real roads.

- I used the first and last point to create a navigation between and set all the other points as 'waypoints', see Directions API
- To find the nearest address of a point, I used the Geocoding API

Google Maps API Webservices: http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/